# How to use INotifyPropertyChanged event on ICollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, inotifypropertychanged

My scenario is below:

I am using EF4 and use linq.
I have a datagrid which is bound to a ICollectionView (bacause I use filtering) as below:

```
view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstOrdsRlsd);
                if (lstOrdsRlsd.Count > 0)
                {
                    dgRecords1.ItemsSource = view;
                }
```

where lstOrdsRlsd is an observablecollection.

My problem is :

I need to refresh the datagrid when something is changed in the database (whether its adding a new row or changing some property of one record etc).

I tried `datagrid.Items.Refresh()` which didnt work.
Can I use INotifyPropertyChanged in this case? Could someone give some sample code about how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the DbSet<>.Local property. This is an observable collection with all the rows that you have queries from you database context.

```
public ObservableCollection<T> DbSet<T>.Local
```

So if you do any queries later, and more rows comes back, the DbSet<>.Local collection will INotifyCollectionChanged for you. :)

So the next step is to then make sure EF fetches the new rows. You could use anything from Daniel Hilgarth's answer to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

A new row in the database is not automatically reflected in your application. You need to manually request the new items from the database and add them to your collection.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. Is it a good idea to use a timer and re-query the database

Comment: I don't know. That totaly depends on your business requirements.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server (not express), then it might be a good idea to use `SqlDependency`/`SqlChangeMonitor`